# Mule ESB - CMIS vs SharePoint connectors

Tags: sharepoint, integration, esb, mule, cmis

Does anybody know if there is any differences between CMIS (http://www.mulesoft.org/muleforge/cmis-cloud-connector) and SharePoint (http://www.mulesoft.com/cloud-connectors/sharepoint) connectors in Mule ESB?

Since CMIS only is supported in SharePoint server 2010 I'm wondering if Mule has a solution for previous versions of SharePoint.

Thanks,
Mohammad

Answer (score 1):

I got the following response from a contact in MuleSoft:

"Regarding SharePoint – you actually use the CMIS connector for that.  CMIS is the underlying technology of SharePoint"

Comment: That's not an accurate statement. I'm not a Microsoft guy, but I am heavily involved with CMIS. Microsoft shipped its first CMIS implementation as a connector for SharePoint 2010 in July of 2010. Before that I don't think SharePoint had a working CMIS implementation.

Comment: The MuleSoft answer is not intrinsically inaccurate, only poorly worded I think. What they probably wanted to say is that CMIS is the underlying technology used by the Mule's SharePoint connector.